# Intersection of sets of multiples of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gre-exam

The question and its answer is shown below:[image]

I do not understand the answer starting from "When this is the case, m and n share all but .......", Could anyone explain this for me?

Comment: For $k$ to be in $P_n\cap P_m$ there must be primes $p,q$ such that $pn=k=qm$.  Thus the prime factorizations of $n,m$ must differ by exchanging one prime factor for another.  $12=2\times2 \times 3,20=2\times 2\times 5$ so we simply exchange $3,5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $\ n\in P_j\cap P_k \iff  \exists p,q\!:\ pj = n = qk\iff \exists p,q\!:\ \dfrac{j}{k} = \dfrac{q}p,\,$  which is equivalent to $\,j/k\,$ being a quotient of *primes* $\,q/p\,$ when reduced to *lowest terms*.

Among $\ \ \dfrac{1}{23},\,\ \ \dfrac{7}{21}\!=\!\dfrac{1}{3},\ \ \dfrac{12}{20}\! =\! \color{#c00}{\dfrac{3}{5}},\,\ \ \dfrac{20}{24}\! =\!\dfrac{5}{6},\,\ \ \dfrac{5}{25}\! =\! \dfrac{1}5\ \ $ only the $\,\rm\color{#c00}{3rd}\,$ reduces to this form.

Comment: I do not understand your last line. could u clarify please?

Comment: yeah I understood :) thank u